# What is the difference between Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb and Microsoft.Owin.Host.IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

As I know [Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb) allows me to run OWIN app on IIS, but today I found another package called [Microsoft.Owin.Host.IIS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.IIS/) that (as I understand from it's name) has similar purpose.

Actually I think that I am wrong and that packages are very different.

So, here the questions:

- What is the difference between that two packages?
- In what case should I use one or another?
- And last (optional): can someone give me a link to good explanation of all that ASP.NET 5 mess? *(Microsoft creates new platforms/frameworks/features faster than document them, so I am feeling quite disoriented now...)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Microsoft creates new platforms/frameworks/features faster than document them

The concurrent development of MVC 6, Katana (OWIN) and ASP.NET 6 isn't really helping to clear the confusion between all that's going on.

As far as I understand it:

The `Microsoft.Owin.Host.IIS` namespace, assembly and package are for [Helios, introduced in this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/18/introducing-asp-net-project-helios.aspx). Basically it's meant to run managed code, without ASP.NET, in IIS - to provide your own OWIN middleware on top of that.

So you seem to need `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` for your purposes. This forms an OWIN host that allows your middleware to use `System.Web`.

Comment: So, as I understand, Helios allows to remove integrated pipeline entirely, so no more event binding (http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline) or another tricky fixes. Just middleware, middleware, middleware - purity :-) I definitely should to try Helios right now.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your optional question:

The problem with `System.Web` is that it is way too bloated and coupled with IIS. As an example, you cannot host an MVC website in a Console Window. You are forced to run it in IIS. The OWIN initiative is an attempt to modularize and decouple the Web Stack by adding abstraction.

In essence, the entire Web Stack is reduced to a pipeline of middleware components (similar to the way node.js does things). A middleware component or `AppFunc` (`Func<IDictionary<string, object>,Task>`) is a function that takes a context (containing request, response and other things...) and does something with it (request parsing, routing, rendering a view, logging stuff, ...). The entire stack then becomes a sequence of middleware components: every component calls the next one in the chain, or breaks execution by not calling the next one.

ASP.NET 5 is a natural evolution in the sense that it builds upon OWIN and as such enables modularity and removes the dependency on System.Web (and IIS). Everything is now opt-in and you can even run applications cross-platform (using .NET Core). This would never be possible without OWIN.

Comment: Thanks, I know that actually (i.e. I know about ASP.NET 5 main goal), just asking for more detailed explanation. Btw, I think that answer is correct and might be useful for somebody else.

Comment: What is the level of detail you expect? :)

Comment: Something like huge blog post (authored by some MS architect maybe) that describes whole ASP.NET 5 ecosystem. Starting from common concepts and finishing with detailed description of each related package. Something  like this I think. Yes, actually it should be a book :-) But don't worry about me, as I said, your answer is absolutely correct - indeed - MS has a dream about totally decoupled system and they remind about it in every ASP.NET 5 screencast...

Comment: ...The bad side: I can't find documentation that verbose enough to explain all that innovations. I am perfectly understand OWIN (and MS implementation called Katana), but I can't catch all that ASP.NET 5 changes. Last try was about three or four months ago, but without success - I found some answers of course, but many important questions are still unanswered - still too many magic - still can't start to use it with confidence.

Comment: Best places to start are live.asp.net and github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues. The first one has the history of all community standups (changes and reasons behind changes plus pointers to community blog posts) and the second lists all breaking changes per release. Also, with every beta release, there is a blogpost on the MSDN blog